# When conjugating adjectives, can we use the normal form of the adjective and use the copula です to indicate its form?

Tags: grammar, politeness, negation, i-adjectives

This is specifically for い-adjectives, as な-adjectives work this way.
For example, when I want to say something is not delicious I'd usually say **おいしくない**.
Would it be possible to use **おいしい じゃありません** and would it mean the same thing?

Comment: Short answer: no you cannot do that.

Comment: おいしいじゃありません(?) might mean "It's delicious, isn't it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would mean the same thing, but wrong in terms of grammar.

---

おいしくない:

- Question おいしくない？ (Delicious, isn't it?) valid
- Statement おいしくない (Not delicious) valid

---

おいしいじゃありません:

- Question おいしいじゃありません？ (Delicious, isn't it?) valid
- Statement おいしいじゃありません **Not valid**

The question "おいしいじゃありません？" is a unique edge case, and you might never use it in your life.

The statement "おいしいじゃありません" looks/sounds wrong although the message is clear you are not enjoying that meal.

---

Possible statements to deny おいしい:

- おいし**く**ありません

Following works too:

- おいしいごはんではありません
- おいしいとは思いません

---

**Edit**:

The above are basics. Hate to add complexity but there is yet another edge case where one is happy with the meal and say:

- Statement おいしいじゃありません (Isn't this delicious)
- Statement おいしいじゃありませんこと (Isn't this delicious)

This carries the same logic as the question, but is not a question. It's somewhere between a rhetorical question and a firm statement. These are advanced expressions which may be used with enough context and correct pronunciation.